# Return Only First Instance of each Occurrence

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a page that shows all the Application Types for a product. 
I have a view dbo.View_Products_by_Application and a table dbo.tblApplications.

dbo.tblApplicaitons has two fields, ApplicationName & ApplicationID

dbo.View_Products_By_Application has all the product information. What I want to do is create a record set that uses dbo.tblApplications and returns only the ApplicationNames where that application Name also Appears in the dbo.View_Produts_by_Application view. And in the recordset returned, I only want each ApplicationName to appear once.

The two items I need in my record set are ApplicationName and ApplicationID.

```
SELECT *
  FROM [WebV2].[dbo].[View_Products_By_Application]
  INNER JOIN dbo.tblApplications
   ON dbo.View_Products_By_Application.ApplicationName = dbo.tblApplications.ApplicationName
   Order BY dbo.View_Products_By_Application.ApplicationName ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just do a `select distinct` to get what you want:

```
SELECT distinct a.ApplicationName, a.ApplicationId
FROM [WebV2].[dbo].[View_Products_By_Application] pba
     INNER JOIN dbo.tblApplications a
      ON pba.ApplicationName = a.ApplicationName
 Order BY a.ApplicationName ASC
```

I also added table aliases to make your query more readable.

Comment: I get the error - Msg 145, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.

Comment: @SeanO'Connor . . . Oops, but the wrong alias on the column in the order by clause.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite get what you have there but I think what you are looking for is something like this.

```
SELECT [WebV2].[dbo].[View_Products_By_Application].*, dbo.tblApplications.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY dbo.View_Products_By_Application.ApplicationName   Order BY dbo.View_Products_By_Application.ApplicationName ASC)
As rownum
 FROM [WebV2].[dbo].[View_Products_By_Application]
 INNER JOIN dbo.tblApplications ON dbo.View_Products_By_Application.ApplicationName = dbo.tblApplications.ApplicationName 
Where rownum= 1
```

This will return to you the first by ApplicationName, I believe.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could use [EXISTS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx):

```
SELECT  app.ApplicationName, app.ApplicationID
FROM    dbo.tblApplications app
WHERE   EXISTS
(
    SELECT  *
    FROM    [WebV2].[dbo].[View_Products_By_Application] vw
    WHERE   vw.ApplicationName = app.ApplicationName
)
ORDER BY app.ApplicationName;
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you so much, I was way over complicating what I needed to do I guess.

Comment: Lets say I need the ApplicationNames to be returned in ASC order, is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: @SeanO'Connor: `... ORDER BY app.ApplicationName;`